# Is there a function which the opposite of NULLIF?

Tags: null, sql-standard

I am aware of the `NULLIF` function which compares two values and returns `NULL` if they match.

Is there a function which will compare two values and return `NULL` if they *don’t* match? That is filter out the other values.

I know I can do something like that using `CASE`:

```
CASE column WHEN value THEN 1 END
```

I also know that I can write a function.

Perhaps there is a subtle trick to using `NULLIF` that I am unaware of.

I think `NULLIF` is generic. I am looking for a solution which is also generic, so that it can be applied to any standard database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NULLIF(expr1, NULLIF(expr1, expr2))` does what you want.

Comment: If both expressions are NULL this will return NULL. That may be acceptable, depending on how you define "match"!

Answer (score -2):

CASE expr1 WHEN expr2 THEN expr1 END

This is the simplest answer I could think of.

Comment: Maybe you could add an example of how exactly to construct the `CASE` statement to return `NULL` when `expr1` and `expr2` don't match?  What about when each value being passed into the `CASE` is `NULL`?

Comment: This form is mentioned in the question already; the asker was asking for an alternative to this.

Comment: The initial post has been edited to mention it. It wasn't there when I've replied. So my answer was correct at this time.